# Traversing an AST callback when finished?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an AST created by babelParser. I want to traverse the nodes to create an array of nodes that match a certain criteria. The problem I seem to have is knowing when the traversing as reached its final point. The code would look something like this...

```
traverseNodes(ast, () => {
 // some act on each node that adds it to an array
}.then((arrayOfMatchNodes) => {
 // some action when ALL nodes have been handled.
}
```

What module could I use 'traverseNodes' here? Every example I have seen of traversing nodes, doesn't seem to have a callback for when its actually finished.

Comment: Good example here. https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#babel-traverse 
Why are you using `.then` it doesn't look like traverse returns a promise to me.

Comment: `traverse` is synchronous. It doesn't need a "finish" callback.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse is synchronous so when it's done next code will be executed.

```
import parser from "@babel/parser";
import traverse from "@babel/traverse";

const code = `function square(n) {
    return n * n;
}`;

const ast = parser.parse(code);
const nodes = [];

traverse(ast, {
    Identifier(path) {
        nodes.push(path);
    }
});

// show all the nodes
console.log(nodes);
```

You can achieve it even simpler with help of my library [Putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) (no need to use `parse` and `traverse`):

```js
import putout from 'putout';

const source = `function square(n) {
    return n * n;
}`;

const nodes = [];

putout(source, {
    plugins: [
        ['collect', {
            report: () => 'collect nodes',
            fix: (path) => nodes.push(path),
            include: () => [
                'Identifier'
            ]
        }]
    ]
});

console.log(nodes);
```

You can find more information about traversing and working with `AST` in [Babel Handbook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md).

Comment: Like yesterday, [please disclose that you are affiliated with putout](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Just write "*…with help of **my library** putout …*".